# Restrict template to largest data type necessary for all calls

Tags: c++, templates

I have some function which computes an operation on numbers:

```
int32_t compute(int32_t x) {
    // just a placeholder; the details don't matter
    return ~x;
}
```

The full function is kind of big, and pulls in other big number functions too. I want to save every byte because it's for an 8-bit microcontroller with a tiny ROM.

*In general* I want to support at least 32-bit inputs, so I used int32_t, but in most builds, it won't be called with more than a 16-bit or even 8-bit input, so hard-coding the type to always be so large is usually a waste.

I could use a template type:

```
template <typename T>
T compute(T x) {
    return ~x;
}
```

Now if it's only used with, for example, 8-bit types, all the 32-bit stuff disappears.

But when this is called with *multiple* types in a particular build, it makes things much worse because now there are multiple copies of the function. I don't need separate specializations for int32_t, int16_t, int8_t, when the int32_t version can satisfy all uses. (I'm not worried about speed, only size.)

So I want only one version of the function, but using a type that can satisfy all uses in the application.

Is there any template, macro, compiler extension, linker magic, etc., that can solve this?

---

**Update:** If I restrict the problem to a single translation unit, does that open up any new approaches?

Comment: Maybe [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Your C++ compiler, when compiling one C++ file, has absolutely no clue, whatsoever, about any other code in any other C++ file. So, if it's compiling one C++ file, and sees that it only has 8-bit values to deal with, it will happily compile the 8-bit version, even if a different C++ file, somewhere, uses the 32-bit version. There's nothing that can be used to change this. This is fundamental to how C++ works.

Comment: One way you could do this is to leverage the preprocessor.  You can have an alias like `using int_t = NATIVE_INT_TYPE;` and then in the makefile define what type `NATIVE_INT_TYPE` is.  This lets you change globally what type your functions use by changing just the compile settings.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What if I restrict the problem to a single translation unit?

Comment: Same thing. A C++ compiler compiles a single translation unit from the beginning to the end. When compiling your function at the beginning, that uses a numeric value for this data type which fits within 8 bytes, the compiler has no knowledge of any function that appears later in the same translation unit that uses a value that can only fit in 32 bytes. And once the earlier function is compiled, it is etched in stone. This is fundamental to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t, at least as flexible as you’ve asked for. The problem is, the widest type in use globally won’t be known until link time… but at that point it’s too late to do anything clever with weak symbols, because the compiled calling code is already expecting to call with a particular integer type. Put differently, the target width needs to be known in each translation unit, but may be affected by other translation units.

Have a configurable macro or typedef to determine the width in use, and turn in compiler warnings for narrowing integers to catch situations where it’s been set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Managing the size of a type across a build is a compile-time issue. Set yourself a #define to fix it.

I do not recommend you redefine any existing integer type. Create your own integer type, and declare that at compile time.

For example:

```
integer compute(integer t) {
  ...
}
```

And in the compile command:

```
-Dinteger=int32_t
```

or:

```
-Dinteger=int16_t
```

etc.

The `-D` command-line flag is equivalent to a `#define integer int32_t`, etc somewhere in your code. If you are using a build system of some sort, set it up so that `integer` (or whatever you call your number type) is required to be defined in the build flags.